# Submit from gerrit to Git

Tags: git, gerrit

I have gerrit server running up and git repository which is connected to this server.
I can checkout from this gerrit server and get sources which is located in git repository. But when I am trying to commit some changes and submit them to Git repository it does not seem like these changes are pushed to git repository.
I edited my `replication.config` file like this:

```
  [remote "Main"]
        url = https://portal-ua.tms.com/git/${name}.git/ 
        push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
        push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

What could be the issue?
 In logs I got following error:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NotSupportedException: remote does not support smart HTTP push
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openPush(TransportHttp.java:378)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1120)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushOp.pushVia(PushOp.java:281)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushOp.runImpl(PushOp.java:226)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushOp.runPushOperation(PushOp.java:179)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushOp.run(PushOp.java:161)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is it possible to push to the git repo from gerrit via http at all?
Thank you on advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not success over http but over ssh it works with the current command:

ssh -p 29418  gerrit review --project $GERRIT_PROJECT --submit  $GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER,$GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER